# Use captured group with regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to use groups with regexes.

Here is my code:

```
std::regex twoWordsCommand{"([a-z]+)\s(\w+)(['('][-]?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?[')'])"};
std::regex_match ("push int32(4242)", twoWordsCommand);
```

The following code works, and it maches. With this regex, I created 3 groups.

Groups should be like that:

```
group 1 = push
group 2 = int32
group 3 = (4242)
```

Now, how can I use those groups?
Let's say I want to transform the word in group1 into a string, so I can then do something with my string being "push". How would I do that?

Like, how would I do:

```
myFunction(group1);
```

myFunction being a function that would then do something with what's inside group1 (in this case: "push").

Thanks

Comment: How is it your regex variable name starts with a number?

Comment: @r3musn0x sorry for that, edited it!

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: @JHBonarius Edited some of my code to make it cleaner. WIll continue reading your link and try to edit things,

Comment: @iNukeLaPeste: You don't seem to be using raw string literals, so unescaped regex like that is dysfunctional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to fix your regex by escaping the backslashes:

```
std::regex twoWordsCommand{"([a-z]+)\\s(\\w+)(['('][-]?[0-9]+(.[0-9]+)?[')'])"};
```

The you should create one of the [std::match_results](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/match_results) objects and pass it to `std::regex_match`:

```
std::cmatch match;
std::regex_match("push int32(4242)", match, twoWordsCommand);
```

then you will be able to access matched groups:

```
std::cout << match[1].str() << std::endl;
```

The code above will output "push". For more examples please see the "Example" section of [std::regex_match reference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match).